# Find and Extracting a string using PHP

Tags: php, string

i am working on a little function for fetching and displaying items from my twitter rss feed. but i am getting it in this format :
Title http://t.co/xxx

what i want is to extract the http://t.co/xx (url) from that string i am getting. 
so i can use it as a link etc.
Help is appreciated :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$item = "Title http://t.co/xxx";
preg_match( "/http\S+/", $item, $matches );
$url = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$title = Title http://t.co/xxx

$final = str_replace("Title ","",$title);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Title http://t.co/xxx';
echo substr($str, strpos($str, 'http'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good time to learn regular expression too :)

try this out

```
<?php
$s = '
Title http://t.co/xxx
Title http://t.co/yyy

';

$s2 = preg_replace( '@(Title |http://t.co/)@i', '', $s );
echo nl2br( $s2 );
?>
```